# Upgrade centos kernel 5

Tags: centos, linux-kernel, upgrade, repository

Try to update kernel latest but not shown in list available kernel. I check the repo list on the mirror site kernel 5 are listed there.

Is there someone have the same issue and solution for it.

[image]

Comment: May be your repo cache is old try to update(in that case update yum cache), or it's baseurl it not in your repo? there is no condition when you can't get package until it is disabled in repo or you are preventing from other way.

Comment: I already update the cache too. On the base url i also check there is kernel 5.1 on elrepo mirror list and a month ago i also install kernel other host (same centos version).

Answer (score 2):

What do you mean by "latest"?  You are using a Linux distribution which comes with a pre-compiled kernel.  CentOS is derived from Redhat.  Redhat backport security and bug fixes, so you don't need to be too caught up in the package versions when compared to upstream sources.  If you run 'yum update' it is getting you the best packages including the kernel available from the repositories.

You should see this FAQ on the topic of backporting...

https://access.redhat.com/security/updates/backporting

If you really must use a kernel straight from kernel.org, in my experience there are other distros which are more congruent with that, as Redhat require certain kernel modules to be in the initramfs.

There are attempts to document how to compile a kernel from source, but it isn't for the faint of heart and I'm not going to do the "Stack Exchange" standard of writing an entire book on how it is done.  I don't think this is what you want, but for the sake of getting a picture of what is involved in kernel compiling, here is a brief online guide.

https://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/compiling-linux-kernel-26.html

Comment: i want to use latest kernel (5.1) because there is some kernel feature on that version. A month a go i update kernel 5.1 on another host with elrepo. On the repository site there is also listed for kernel 5.1.

Comment: I wasn't familiar with elrepo.  They have 2 kernel branches : lt and ml.  You can see the available RPMs at the site https://elrepo.org/linux/kernel/el7/x86_64/RPMS/
I only see the ml branch listed for 5.1.  Did you follow the instructions for ml branch?  http://elrepo.org/tiki/kernel-ml

Comment: i already solved the problem using yum utils and query to the elrepo repository then run 'repoquery --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel -qi kernel-ml' after that run 'yum --enablerepo=elrepo-kernel install kernel-ml' and voila, works like a charm.